# Finding highest frequency from the recorded sound-includes FFT

Tags: java, android, fft, audiorecord

I am working on a project where i have to create a Tone Listener such that i can record a tone using AudioRecord class of Android. This tone listener will listen to the tone and then will give out the frequency of the tone. I am using FFT for getting the frequency but am stuck as it does not give me the exact frequency. Is there any way that can work?
I am in search of FFT and audio record class of android.
The snippet of the code is as follows:

```
                       while (isListening) {

                            for (int t = 0; t <= 5; t++) {

                                // System.out.println("Inside for loop");
                                int numberOfShortsRead = audioRecord
                                        .read(audioData,
                                                audioSize,
                                                (kRecorderNumberOfSamples - audioSize));

                                // System.out.println("Read"+numberOfShortsRead);

                                if (numberOfShortsRead > 0) {
                                    System.out.println("inside read>0");
                                    System.out.println("Number of read"
                                            + numberOfShortsRead);

                                    audioSize += numberOfShortsRead;

                                    System.out
                                            .println("Final audio data size"
                                                    + audioSize);

                                    System.out.println("Number Of Samples"
                                            + kRecorderNumberOfSamples);

                                    if (kRecorderNumberOfSamples == audioSize) {

                                        for (int i = 0; i < audioSize; i++) {
                                            x[i] = audioData[i]; // real
                                            y[i] = 0; // imaginary
                                        }

                                        System.out.println("Inside FFT"
                                                + "x" + x + "y" + y);

                                        int i, j, k, n1, n2, a;
                                        double c, s, t1, t2;
                                        // Bit-reverse
                                        j = 0;
                                        n2 = n / 2;
                                        for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
                                            n1 = n2;
                                            while (j >= n1) {
                                                j = j - n1;
                                                n1 = n1 / 2;
                                            }
                                            j = j + n1;
                                            if (i < j) {
                                                t1 = x[i];
                                                x[i] = x[j];
                                                x[j] = t1;
                                                t1 = y[i];
                                                y[i] = y[j];
                                                y[j] = t1;
                                            }
                                        }

                                        // FFT

                                        n1 = 0;
                                        n2 = 1;

                                        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                                            n1 = n2;
                                            n2 = n2 + n2;
                                            a = 0;

                                            for (j = 0; j < n1; j++) {
                                                c = cos[a];
                                                s = sin[a];
                                                a += 1 << (m - i - 1);

                                                for (k = j; k < n; k = k
                                                        + n2) {
                                                    t1 = c * x[k + n1] - s
                                                            * y[k + n1];
                                                    t2 = s * x[k + n1] + c
                                                            * y[k + n1];
                                                    x[k + n1] = x[k] - t1;
                                                    y[k + n1] = y[k] - t2;
                                                    x[k] = x[k] + t1;
                                                    y[k] = y[k] + t2;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
```

Comment: for better help sooner, please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Here is the snippet of the code:

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your FFT algorithm works, to get the most prominent frequency in your audio data you have to find the frequency where the magnitude is greatest.So in other words find the FFT data point(s) that have the highest magnitude.If you want a more precise values of frequencies you will need to use a higher N to get more resolution.

Hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

Frequency estimation methods, such as parabolic interpolation of windowed FFT magnitude peaks (or Sinc interpolation of the complex FFT results) might provide a closer estimate of an exact frequency, as will using more data with a longer FFT, which provides more closely spaced FFT frequency result bins.  You may have to buffer up more recorded samples until you have enough use that longer FFT.  Zero-padding before a longer FFT is also another method of interpolation for frequency estimation, but the result will be noisier and thus less accurate than using more data.